# BigQuery data load strategy suggestions

Tags: google-bigquery

I have date partitioned tables. Currently, the way we deal with updates on these tables is :

a) by having the Write Disposition set to Write_Truncate on the partitions, so that we flush the entire data partition out for THOSE days in question
b) AND then, for days where we have updated data, we load the ENTIRE day's data again.

So, in other words, even if there is 1 record updated in a date partition which has 100,000 records, we flush the entire partition and reload it. This is a little costly and inefficient.

Is there another better way to do it where we can just run updates ? How will it work on existing tables partitioned on date and which have GBs of data in it ? What Write disposition do i use in such cases ?

Any code examples or pointers on this ?

Comment: why don't you run an `UPDATE` or `MERGE` command?

Comment: The updates i have are plenty i.e. of the order of tens of thousands and i don't think BQ supports that many updates

Comment: Do you need to run a different `UPDATE` every second, or could you batch these, and run a large `UPDATE` every 5 minutes, or once an hour, or...?

Comment: It's actually a daily activity. I have to fetch about 300 days of data ; The first 10 days (0<T<10) of data have about 50k updates for each day, the next set 40 days (10<T<50) have about 1000 updates each, the next 50 days (50<T<100) have about 100 records per day each and so on and so forth... the records to update go on decreasing as i go further back in time

Comment: Then if you have a big amount of updates, but you can have them all happen at the same time.. then run just one `MERGE` or `UPDATE`. It doesn't matter if they are a lot (if they are group together in one op)

Comment: Something like this : 

MERGE table_to_be_Updated         A
USING table_FROM_which_Updatedvalue are to be fetched  B
ON 
  A.field1 = B.field1
  AND A.field2  = B.field2
  AND A.field3 = B.field3
  AND A.field4 = B.field4
  AND A.field5 = B.field5
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET 
  A.field10 = B.field10 ,
  A.field11 = B.field11 ,
................
  A.field30 = B.field130 ,

Comment: can you add to the question an example of running one update? let's see what we can do